# Looking for a comprehensive ICO dataset (prices & dates)

Tags: historical-trade-data, ico-initial-coin-offering

I'm working on a short research project on the performance of ICOs and how that relates to the overall sentiment in the crypto market. Unfortunately, I've had no luck so far looking for the required data. I need data on ICO dates and prices as well as price series for the post-ICO period. I've so far only found disjoint sources and no comprehensive dataset. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I would want that data if I was trying to train [Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer)) to predict things. Hopefully, somebody with an insight into what you need will be along before too long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing an open source software to unify all these disjoint sources in one database. I've found an [interesting free API service (IcoBench)](https://icobench.com/developers) that have a lot of information for ICOs, like prices, team, even ratings and a lot of more. The post ICO prices are not stored, but you can use [coinmarketcap.com](https://www.coinmarketcap.com) for search historical prices after the ICO was ended and be launched to the markets. I've developed an API wrapper and web scraper for that page that works in Python, [check out](https://github.com/mondeja/pymarketcap).

I will advise when the project will be more advanced. Currently, this kind of open source unification is a huge neccesary work in cryptoworld. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

here another sources to complement... https://www.dropbox.com/s/m53zfszs6oldtn0/ICO%20Data%20Export.xlsx?dl=0
you may find here some info with datasets
https://medium.com/@MLJARofficial/predicting-ico-returns-with-machine-learning-af6108ab9e39